# Matching `terminfo` capabilities

Tags: terminfo

Is there a way to match terminal/console features with entries in terminfo database?

For example, to find a closest [match to Windows console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44596128/terminfo-for-windows-console) or other type of non-traditional terminal.

There are no online services, so I expect that the problem is non-trivial and it is interesting to know why.

**UPDATE**: Terminfo database gives a set of features for a known terminal type or name. I am trying to do the reverse task - match features of unknown terminal against existing terminfo entries.

**UPDATE2**: How it should work...

1. I select my terminal capabilities from a long list
2. Matcher finds profiles that are either

   - 2.1. implement all those capabilities exactly with no other capabilities
   - 2.2. implement almost all capabilities exactly with no other capabilities
   - 2.3. implement capabilities exactly with some other capabilities
   - 2.4. implement almost all capabilities and adds some other capabilities

Comment: Please describe what kind of matching you're thinking about. What exactly is it you're trying to do?

Comment: After all your edits I still have no idea what you want. What do you mean by "terminal capabilities"?

Comment: @melpomene these?-http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node127.html#SECTION009221000000000000000

Comment: So ... just the booleans? Because I don't get how you're going to select string capabilities from a list. Or even just numbers.

Comment: @melpomene I am not yet skilled in `terminfo` to understand all that details. I am on Windows where all these concept are "alien".

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/terminfo.5.html

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your question. Try this, with `ncurses` package installed:

```
infocmp | grep _Cap_name_
```

or

```
infocmp _terminfo_name_ | grep _Cap_name_
```

and

```
infocmp [-d|-c|-n] _wanted_ _have_
```

`infocmp` compares the contents of two terminfo *terminals*, or displays the terminfo entry (binary) as termcap (human readable text)

On my system terminfo(s) are here:

```
/usr/share/terminfo
/lib/terminfo
```

I reference `_Cap_name_` [here at opengroup.org](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcurses/terminfo.html)

Because you are on Windows (probably without Cygwin) you may have to manually check the capabilities of the `TERM`s you expect, and build in workarounds based on that pre-knowledge, but its Windows, so there can't be that many.

```
TERMINFO=/user/share/terminfo toe
```

This gets you a list of terminals. If you have control over the server, add a terminfo file yourself, write it as text in either `termcap` format then convert it or in `terminfo` info format and then compile it. That way you can start with `dummy+linewrap`. Or try `ansi+idl`.

NOTE: I agree with the other comment about using a VT100/VT102 library.

Answer (score 1):

According to your revised OP, again using `ncurses` library, C you can query the terminal using `tget`. I am not aware of a way to iterate the capabilities without knowing what they might be before making a call to `tget`, however I know that it will return `0` for capabilities that return integer values and are not found, eg. `cMax = tget("max_colors");`.

According to terminfo, when compiling a terminal info configuration, it is possible to provide, (1st) over-rides, (2nd) included terminals, optionally (3rd) excluding included terminals with certain capabilities. This however still requires write access to the target server terminfo database directory, so your resulting terminfo file can be uploaded.

The terminfo database provides *both* a way for servers to provide a terminal, *AND* for programs (including remote ones) to interpret a provided terminal.

Comment: Does `tget` run actual tests to find features?

Comment: Not a test of the capability, just the result of the terminal output. Not sure if it checks the terminfo db reference or just directly to the terminal. Both should return 0 if not set, but the terminal might reply "capability not supported". You will have to read the terminfo programming documentation to know for sure.

Comment: I have some code, and `MaxColors` or `colors` can return `0` according to that code.

Answer (score 0):

So far the answer is http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/terminfo.5.html so I will post better results when I get more time.